# Installation process of wso2 Enterprise integrator

Tags: wso2, integration, wso2-esb, enterprise, ei

Could anyone please let me know how to install latest version of wso2 ei. I've been referring to official documentation but the page isn't clear about the download process and in the product page I'm getting only Micro Integrator 4.2 version for download are both EI and MI same or what? But i have to download EI 7.x version. Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0):

The newer version of the EI is called MI. So both are more or less the same. So you can go ahead with MI 4.2.0 which is the latest version. If you want to download EI 7.2 also known as MI 1.2 you can download it from [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/download/v1.2.0/wso2mi-1.2.0.zip).

Answer (score 0):

The release journey of WSO2 spans from Enterprise Integrator (EI) to Micro Integrator (MI) versions, evolving in terms of simplicity and lightweight design.

Initially, the EI series progressed as follows:

- EI 6.0.0
- EI 6.1.1
- EI 6.2.0
- EI 6.3.0
- EI 6.4.0
- EI 6.5.0
- EI 6.6.0

Post-EI 6.6.0, WSO2 opted for a leaner approach, shedding heavy components like the Management UI and introducing Micro Integrator. The transition to MI commenced with:

- MI 1.0.0 (previously known as EI 7.0.0)
- MI 1.2.0 (formerly EI 7.1.0,marking the abandonment of the EI nomenclature)
- MI 4.0.0
- MI 4.1.0
- MI 4.2.0

For downloading, only the latest supported MI versions—MI 4.0.0, MI 4.0.1, MI 4.1.0, and MI 4.2.0—are available on the official WSO2 site. Refer to WSO2's support matrix[1] to discern between deprecated and current products.

If you seek EI 7.x versions, you can access them via the WSO2 official Github repository[2] and build the product manually.

Considering that EI 7.x corresponds to MI 1.x, it's advisable to leverage the latest MI 4.2.0 version, which incorporates significant improvements over time.

[1].https://wso2.com/products/support-matrix/

[2].https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/releases/tag/v1.2.0